# Can I have Chrome DevTools open during the page load?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

It's common I want to have the DevTools open while a page refreshes. Can I have the DevTools available to debug that page from the start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remote debug your own Chrome instance to get a full DevTools for every page.
[Start Chrome with the command line flag](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags): `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

You then get a UI like:

[image]

From here you select which tab you'd like to debug and it'll open up the DevTools in an exclusive window for that page:

[image]